# Unable to start PhantomJS with Ghostdriver: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I am writing python script which is using selenium WebDriver and PhantomJS.

My code is stuck at this error

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

I have gone through every single threads related to this error and tried all solutions. So please do not mark it as duplicate.

I am running everything as administrator.
I tried changing UAC setting as well.

My configuration:

Python 3.5. 
Windows 10 (64 bit)

Here is my python code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:/Users/USER/Python/Demo');
driver.get("https://49erexpress.uncc.edu/cp/home/displaylogin") # Open homepage

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "login_username").send_keys("user");
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "login_password").send_keys("****");
driver.execute_script("return login()");
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Class Schedule').click();  # Click on class schedule

driver.switch_to_default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("content"))
#driver.switch_to.frame("content")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
#link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Add/Drop/Withdraw Classes')))  # Click on Add/Drop/Withdraw Classes
link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[text()='Add/Drop/Withdraw Classes']"))) # Click on Add/Drop/Withdraw Classes
link.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame("content")

link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Submit']")))  # Click on Submit button
link.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame("content")

driver.find_element(By.ID, "crn_id1").send_keys("16595");
link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Submit Changes']")))  # Click on submit changes
link.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame("content")

link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//td[contains(text(),'16595')]/preceding-sibling::td")))
```

And here is the error that I am getting.

```
    "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\python.exe" C:/Users/USER/Python/Demo/main_update2.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 73, in start
        stdout=self._log, stderr=self._log)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 855, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 1125, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/USER/Python/Demo/main_update2.py", line 10, in 
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:/Users/USER/Python/Demo');
      File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
        self.service.start()
      File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 76, in start
        raise WebDriverException("Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver: %s" % e)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver: [WinError 5] Access is denied


    Process finished with exit code 1
```

This issue got resolved when I added this line. "driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)". Can anyone tell me why it was generating access denied error?

Comment: This issue got resolved when I added this line. "driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)".
Can anyone tell me why it was generating access denied error ?

Comment: FWIW, phantomjs driver support has been removed from Selenium